# Python dictionary and list to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, list, dictionary

```
result={'text': ' A nation is a community of people formed on the basis of a combination of shared features. A nation is thus the collective identity of a group of people understood as defined by those features.',
'segments': [{'id': 0,
   'seek': 0,
   'start': 0.54,
   'end': 5.08,
   'text': ' A nation is a community of people formed on the basis of a combination of shared features.',
   'tokens': [50364,13858,],
   'temperature': 0.0,
   'avg_logprob': -0.3795953684839709,
   'compression_ratio': 1.9613899613899615,
   'no_speech_prob': 0.0013710602652281523,
   'confidence': 0.607,
   'words': [****{'text': 'a', 'start': 0.54, 'end': 1.3, 'confidence': 0.613},
    {'text': 'nation', 'start': 1.3, 'end': 1.98, 'confidence': 0.585},
    {'text': 'is', 'start': 1.98, 'end': 2.54, 'confidence': 0.974},
    {'text': 'community', 'start': 2.54, 'end': 3.04, 'confidence': 0.808},
    {'text': 'of', 'start': 3.04, 'end': 3.48, 'confidence': 0.807},
    {'text': 'people', 'start': 3.48, 'end': 3.86, 'confidence': 0.764},
    {'text': 'form', 'start': 3.86, 'end': 4.24, 'confidence': 0.477},
    {'text': 'on.', 'start': 4.24, 'end': 5.08, 'confidence': 0.29}****]},
  {'id': 1,
   'seek': 0,
   'start': 5.38,
   'end': 9.72,
   'text': ' the basis of a combination of shared features',
   'tokens': [50614,4704],
   'temperature': 0.0,
   'avg_logprob': -0.3795953684839709,
   'compression_ratio': 1.9613899613899615,
   'no_speech_prob': 0.0013710602652281523,
   'confidence': 0.865,
   'words': [****{'text': 'the', 'start': 5.38, 'end': 5.8, 'confidence': 0.813},
    {'text': 'basis', 'start': 5.8, 'end': 6.2, 'confidence': 0.886},
    {'text': 'of', 'start': 6.2, 'end': 6.54, 'confidence': 0.961},
    {'text': 'a', 'start': 6.54, 'end': 7.14, 'confidence': 0.612},
    {'text': 'combination', 'start': 7.14, 'end': 7.8, 'confidence': 0.887},
    {'text': 'of', 'start': 7.8, 'end': 8.18, 'confidence': 0.971},
    {'text': 'shared', 'start': 8.18, 'end': 8.5, 'confidence': 0.895},
    {'text': 'features', 'start': 8.5, 'end': 8.72, 'confidence': 0.88}****]},
  {'id': 2,
 same like above
  .
  .
  .
  .
  ],
 'language': 'ko'}
```

this is the value of 'result'. and i want to make the values ​​corresponding to the surrounded by ****(next to 'words') into a data frame with column names text, start, end. please tell me the python code......

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the DataFrames made from the values (lists) associated with the `words` key for each segment:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(segment['words']) for segment in result['segments']])
```

Output (for id 0 and 1 in your example):

```
          text  start   end  confidence
0            a   0.54  1.30       0.613
1       nation   1.30  1.98       0.585
2           is   1.98  2.54       0.974
3    community   2.54  3.04       0.808
4           of   3.04  3.48       0.807
5       people   3.48  3.86       0.764
6         form   3.86  4.24       0.477
7          on.   4.24  5.08       0.290
0          the   5.38  5.80       0.813
1        basis   5.80  6.20       0.886
2           of   6.20  6.54       0.961
3            a   6.54  7.14       0.612
4  combination   7.14  7.80       0.887
5           of   7.80  8.18       0.971
6       shared   8.18  8.50       0.895
7     features   8.50  8.72       0.880
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(result, record_path=["segments", "words"])
```

Result:

```
           text  start   end  confidence
0             a   0.54  1.30       0.613
1        nation   1.30  1.98       0.585
2            is   1.98  2.54       0.974
3     community   2.54  3.04       0.808
4            of   3.04  3.48       0.807
5        people   3.48  3.86       0.764
6          form   3.86  4.24       0.477
7           on.   4.24  5.08       0.290
8           the   5.38  5.80       0.813
9         basis   5.80  6.20       0.886
10           of   6.20  6.54       0.961
11            a   6.54  7.14       0.612
12  combination   7.14  7.80       0.887
13           of   7.80  8.18       0.971
14       shared   8.18  8.50       0.895
15     features   8.50  8.72       0.880
```